# Get sum of row differences with Pandas .diff()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am doing a time-series analysis where I need to calculate the change in several attributes over time. Pandas makes a simple version of this easy; the .diff(periods=n) function will calculate the difference between a row and the preceding n rows, however, that is not *quite* what I need...

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'day_num': [134, 135, 136, 137],
                    'swe': [38.8, 38.9, 37.6, 36.8],
                     'prcp': [0., 0.1, 0., 0.15],
                     'flow': [2930, 3350, 3900, 4090]})

diff_3 = df.diff(periods=3)
```

returns:

```
   day_num   swe  prcp  flow
0      134  38.8  0.00  2930
1      135  38.9  0.00  3350
2      136   37.6  0.00  3900
3      137  36.8  0.15  4090
```

And:

```
  day_num  swe  prcp    flow
0      NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN
1      NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN
2      NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN
3      3.0 -2.0  0.15  1160.0
```

In the swe column(snow water equivalent in inches, literally the liquid water equivalent of a particular snowpack) , the 3 day difference for index 3 is -2.0, which equals 36.8 - 38.8. However, notice that there was an increase and decrease within the 3 day period. This means that a total of 2.1 inches (my desired output) of water melted and contributed to  streamflow (flow column) over that 3 day window. Min - max would not work either, because if I were to increase the n value to 7 or 14, there could easily be 'meltings' that are not accounted for in the output. What is needed is the sum of the single day differences over a span of n days. I eventually want to merge the diff_n columns back into the original dataset.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Also, this is my first post so let me know how I can improve my format / content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sum of the single day differences over a span of n days

First, `diff` consecutive rows then do a [rolling sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html). Since the series after `diff` already has difference for 2 consecutive rows, for rolling sum we only provide `period-1` (in our case `3-1 = 2`).

```
periods = 3
df['swe'] = df['swe'].diff().rolling(periods-1).sum()
```

**Output:**

```
   day_num  swe  prcp  flow
0      134  NaN  0.00  2930
1      135  NaN  0.10  3350
2      136 -1.2  0.00  3900
3      137 -2.1  0.15  4090
```

This is also equivalent to doing following as the contribution of intermediate days will eventually cancel out:

```
df['swe'] = df['swe'].diff(periods-1)
```

**Output:**

```
   day_num   swe  prcp  flow  swe_using_diff  swe_using_rolling_sum
0      134  38.8  0.00  2930             NaN                    NaN
1      135  38.9  0.10  3350             NaN                    NaN
2      136  37.6  0.00  3900            -1.2                   -1.2
3      137  36.8  0.15  4090            -2.1                   -2.1
```